# zabbix 3.2 - external script not working

Tags: zabbix

I have installed zabbix and running an external script - here is the steps I followed :

1. created a /etc/zabbix/externalscripts directory with correct rights
2. copied the script to this directory,
3. On web interface `Administration` -> `Scripts` -> `new script`
   In the `commands` section - > `/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/check.py https://mywebsite.com`
4. Also create an item with type `External Check` and key is the file name of the script `check.py` and type of information is `Numeric`
5. Create a `graph` - > added the item I created above to plot - but the status already says `Not Supported`. If I change the type to character it never shows up in the items.

So now I get an error in the logs

> ÏndexError:list index out of range]is not suitable for value type [numeric unsigned] and data type [decimal]

What I have checked:

I ran the script from the command prompt and it executes with the result:

```
OK, Total Resp Time: 8334.55ms;|8321.55
```

I am not sure what else I need to check. Have changed the type to `Float` etc without any help.
The permissions to the directory is fine.
Any help would be appreciated.
zabbix version 3.2 running on centos 7

Answer (score 1):

First, there was no need to add Administration -> Scripts for external checks.

Second, if your script returns "OK, Total Resp Time: 8334.55ms;|8321.55", that is not a number and cannot be put in a numeric item and you will not be able to see a graph of such a string, of course.

Third, the error when running it manually looks like yet another problem. Make sure two things are covered when you run it manually:

- run it as the Zabbix user
- make sure there are no environment variables that affect the script behaviour; if there are, handle that in the script itself

Comment: Thanks - I now changed so the output is just a number like 8334.22 and changed the item to float. It still does not work. So now its like this :                  check.py["{HOST.CONN}"] is the key whereas the script runs well from the command line if I type check.py https://mywebsite.com and returns a number.  The error that I get now is "No schema supplied. is not suitable for value type [Numeric (unsigned)] and data type [Decimal]". I have run it as a zabbix user and it does work well

Comment: Did you check for environment variables having effect on the script operation? Where does the `No schema supplied` error come from?